# Flux changes color quickly

Tags: colors, f.lux

I've been using [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) which is a desktop color management software which adjusts the color of screen to reduce blues during night time.

My understanding is that's meant to slowly adjust the color as your day your day goes on.

However, I've been noticing that it will change rather rapidly, suddenly over about 2 seconds.

Is this a common issue, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Which OS are you using it in? https://justgetflux.com/news/2014/10/28/profile.html & https://justgetflux.com/faq.html  there are many communications in thier own information , what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

There's a setting to make the transition run over an hour.

[From the FAQ](https://justgetflux.com/faq.html):

> This changes too fast, it always shocks me.
>
> The f.lux transition can be CPU intensive, so f.lux
>   tries to be polite about it.
>   To make it slow, you can use the special 1-hour slow transition option under settings instead.

[image: f.lux settings screen]

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to your problem with f.lux, but I just switched away from it for the same reason and I have been using [redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift) with much better results (and customization possibilities).